# Trying to match a finite set of array elements to a string via a regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is what I've come up with:

```
function isValid(str){
    var letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','Z','N','L','Q','R'];
    var parsedStr= str.trim().split(/\s+/); //returns array of each phrase seperated by a space, ex: ['Za', 'Nj']
    if( (new RegExp( '\\b' + parsedStr.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b') ).test(str) ) {
         console.log('match');
    }
}
```

However I dont think I've set this up right. Ideally I want it to parse the string by spaces and play them into an array(which i've already done), and then check via Regex whether the each letter in the parsedStr matches with the CONST of the accepted letters.

For example

`isValid("Za Zy")` => not a match because y is not a valid char in the CONST of accepted characters

`isValid("Za Qf")` => match because every letter in this expression is found in the CONST array of letters.

I know I need to incorporate a loop somewhere but not sure how :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate regex which matches combination of white space and array elements

```js
function isValid(str) {
  var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'Z', 'N', 'L', 'Q', 'R'];
  if ((new RegExp('^[\\s' + letters.join('') + ']+$')).test(str)) {
    console.log('match ' + str);
  } else {
    console.log('not match ' + str);
  }
}

isValid("Za Zy")
isValid("Za Qf")
```

Comment: ok thanks I figured my rexeg was off. I need to work on that aspect of my coding more :/ Ill upvote in 5 mins.